# java - Why is this for-loop giving a nullpointer exception?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, nullpointerexception

Hi there i'm creating a small game for school, but when i try to do this to fill out the x and y variables in this array i get a NPE.
Could anyone help?

```
public class mainclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gra piece[] = new Gra[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < piece.length; i++) {
            piece[i].x = 50;
            piece[i].y = 50;
        }
    }
}

class Gra{
    public int x = 50;
    public int y = 10;
}
```

Comment: Show us the stacktrace. On which line are you getting it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Gra piece[] = new Gra[10];
```

does not initialize objects inside the array, it only creates array, so call constructor to create `Gra`s

```
for (int i = 0; i < piece.length; i++) {
   piece[i] = new Gra();
   piece[i].x = 50;
   piece[i].y = 50;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The statement

```
Gra piece[] = new Gra[10];
```

will only initialize the array. It won't create `Gra` objects.

Inside the `for loop`, you still have to call the constructor as

```
for (int i = 0; i < piece.length; i++) {
    piece[i] = new Gra();
    piece[i].x = 50;
    piece[i].y = 50;
}
```

Also, read more about `encapsulation`. Its a `bad idea` to make `instance variables public`.

Answer (score 1):

You have initialized `gra array` but you did not create `Object` so there is no Object inside the array and by default null is initialized, so `piece[i].x` is actually `null.x` which throws NPE.

```
    Gra piece[] = new Gra[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < piece.length; i++) {
        piece[i] = new Gra();
        piece[i].x = 50;
        piece[i].y = 50;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a an array of Gra with 10 elements.

```
Gra piece[] = new Gra[10];
```

But each element in that array is currently pointing to null.

You need to initialize those individual elements as Java's default value for Object is null.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are just creating Array of type `Gra` By

```
Gra piece[] = new Gra[10];
```

So by default this is `null` .

So first initialize them like

```
for (int i = 0; i < piece.length; i++) {
       pirce[i] =  new Gra();
    }
```

Then do

```
    for (int i = 0; i < piece.length; i++) {
        piece[i].x = 50;
        piece[i].y = 50;
    }
```

Comment: you do not need two loops to do this.

Comment: @tausun  yes you are right but i did just for better explanation.