# Java: nullpointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

In my code I'm trying to accept the arguments and put it in the the array of objects called `cl`. It gives me `NullPointerException`.

```
//In my main class
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    cl[] Array1;  
    Array1 = new cl[n];
    cl[0].a1 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    cl[0].a2 = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
}
```

and

```
//another class declaration
public class cl {
    int a1;
    int a2;
}
```

I'm getting a `NullPointerException`, I'm able to print the command line arguments. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: what is `arr[] Array1;`? is your code not give *compile time* error?

Comment: `cl[0].a1` should be `Array1[0].a1`. Similarly for the other field access.

Comment: Please, *please* start using proper naming conventions. Classes start uppercase, variables start lowercase.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java - Why is this for-loop giving a nullpointer exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576807/java-why-is-this-for-loop-giving-a-nullpointer-exception) among numerous others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 cl[]  Array1 = new cl[n];
```

but your object is null because you haven't initialized your object of `cl[]`

for example.

```
Array1[0]= new cl();
```

and than access the variables.

`Array1[0].a1` and `Array1[0].a2`

As you are doing this

```
cl[0].a1 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

cl  is not your array variable your variable is `Array1`
```

Answer (score 2):

Initializing an array does not initialize its elements.

This

```
 Array1 = new cl[n];
```

creates an array of type `cl` with `n` elements, but those are all initialized to `null` since `cl` is a reference type.

You need to first initialize the element before accessing its field

```
Array1[0] = new cl();
Array1[0].a1 = ...
```

---

Try to follow Java naming conventions. Always start variable names with a lower case character. Always start class names with an upper case character.

Comment: I think you mean `Array1[0] = new c1();` and `Array1[0].a1 = ...`

Comment: @Jason Yeah, copy paste error from OP's snippet. Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem

Answer (score 1):

In the following lines:

```
c1[] Array1;  
Array1 = new cl[n];
```

you are creating an array in which to store references to `c1`.

Then you start dereferencing `c1[0]` when you really mean `Array1[0]`, but you never created an instance of `c1` and put it in `Array1[0]`.

What you need to do is:

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    cl[] Array1;  

    Array1 = new cl[n];

    // don't forget to create an instance of c1 and put in array at index 0!
    Array1[0] = new c1();

    Array1[0].a1 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    Array1[0].a2 = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
}
```

Comment: Jason I think it must be `Array1[0] = new c1()`;